# Executable does not wait for curl to finish downloading

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have an executable which is supposed to download a zip file from a link and unzip it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo “Downloading project resources from Storage...”

if curl -O -J -L https://mylink.com; then
    unzip filename.zip
else

    echo "Something went wrong"
fi;
echo "Done!"
```

However, somehow my script does not wait for `curl` to finish downloading before unzipping the file. What am I doing wrong?

Output:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ ej$ /Users/ej/Desktop/untitled\ folder\ 2/Setup ; exit;
“Downloading project resources from Storage...”
unzip:  cannot find or open file.zip, file.zip.zip or file.zip.ZIP.
Done!
logout
Saving session...  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And in the end no file has been downloaded nor unzipped inside the folder the executable has been ran in.

Edit 2:

`ls -l` outputs the following after I run the curl command in the terminal:

```
-rwxr--r--@ 1 ej  staff       390  2 Apr 21:42 Setup
-rw-r--r--  1 ej  staff  86368932  2 Apr 22:19 file.zip?alt=media
```

`which bash` outputs the following:

```
/bin/bash
```

P.S. Is curl preinstalled on MacBooks?

Comment: Can you please paste the exact output that you get ? What makes you think that the download has not completed ?

Comment: @akskap I have edited my question above.

Comment: Looks like the filename you are trying to access with `unzip` is different from what gets downloaded. Can you paste the output of `ls -l` after running just the curl command in your terminal. Please also tell the output of `which bash`

Comment: @akskap, updated again

Comment: Thanks for the details - posted a revised version of the script below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would suggest the following changes to the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Downloading project resources from Storage..."

filename="outfile.zip"

if curl --silent -o "${PWD}/${filename}" -L "https://mylink.com"; then
    unzip "${filename}"
    if [[ -f "${PWD}/${filename}" ]]; then
        echo "Removing the file.."
        rm -f "${PWD}/${filename}"
    fi
else
    echo "Something went wrong"
fi
echo "Done!"
```

Comment: I'd put the URL in quotes too, in case it has a & or the like.

Comment: @akskap This worked like a charm. However, it downloads and unzips the file in the home directory of the computer rather than inside the current folder. How can I make it extract the files in the current folder and also delete the zip file after unzipping?

Comment: You can use the `PWD` (present working directory) variable in the pathname and `rm` command to remove the file after unzip is done. Modified the answer with new changes

Comment: @akskap Thank you. It now deletes the zip file however, the file is still downloaded and extracted in the home directory of the computer instead the current folder. What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this:

```
curl -O -J -L https://mylink.com && unzip filename.zip
```

this will uzip file if curl execute successfully.